# JaversException PROPERTY_ACCESS_ERROR: error getting value from property 'Method ClassRepository getGenericInfo

Tags: java, javers

I seem to get this error on many classes I'm trying to log (though not all). It looks like a common error, wonder if anyone else saw this and how it got solved.

`JaversException PROPERTY_ACCESS_ERROR: error getting value from property 'Method ClassRepository getGenericInfo; //declared in: Class' on target object of type 'Class', cause: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getGenericInfo() is the method declared in Class class. If you trying to compare classes (objects of type Class) that's not going to work by default. There should be a Custom Comparator for Class type, which would compare class by name.

```
javersBuilder.registerValue(Class.class, (a,b) -> a.getName().equals(b.getName());
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't need to compare classes, they just got 'automatically' compared due to how Javers used to work (take all fields not marked as ignored) and because I didn't annotate my entire domain model - it was too complex. Once switching to only logging 'includedProperties' that issue went away.